# Free, easy to learn D&D-like game.

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

What is the best way to share a free role playing game? I've painstakingly worked to make it easy to understand and play. I'm giving it away to get my works out in the gaming world.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackExchange. It looks like you're new, and we hope you enjoy your time here. One of the things I've noticed with your question is that it seems to be too broad for the purposes of the site. You might want to consider revising it to try to narrow it down a little.

Answer (score -3):

You might want to try [1km1kt.net](http://www.1km1kt.net/), [DriveThruRPG](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/), and [RPG.net](https://www.rpg.net/) (and the forums for 1km1kt and RPG.net in particular) as potential places to distribute and/or spread the word about your game and get it out there.